# How create a notification in AppDelegate after receiving the push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to send a notification to an Android and iOS App.

In Android, I create a service to receive the messages and create a custom notification when the app is active and in background

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMService";


AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> myTask;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    text = remoteMessage.getData().get("text");

    title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");

    addNotification()
}

public void addNotification(boolean HasImage)
{
    intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Resources res = getBaseContext().getResources();

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder ;

    mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_ico))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconbar)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setAutoCancel( true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(notifyId, mNotificationBuilder.build());
}
```

In iOS, I can receive completed notifications, generated by Firebase, and receive messages.

```
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {


func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)

    var title = ""
    var text = ""

    for value in remoteMessage.appData
    {
        if (value.0 as! String) == "title"
        {
            title = value.1 as! String
        }
        if (value.0 as! String) == "text"
        {
            text = value.1 as! String
        }
    }

    self.scheduleLocal(title, text: text)
}

 func scheduleLocal(title: String, text: String)
{
    let settings =     UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

    if settings!.types == .None
    {
        return
    }

    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    notification.fireDate = NSDate()

    notification.alertBody = text

    notification.alertAction = title

    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

         UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

My question is, can I create an Android Service Analog in Xcode? Can you write me a little example to create a notification when app is in background?

Comment: Starting from iOS 10, there's no need to create local notification yourself, you can display the message directly when receiving a push notification.